# How to exclude NA values from being counted in dplyr summarize()?

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a dataset with only NA values, and I'm trying to produce a table that shows that this particular dataset is 100% missing.

But the output shows that the NA value is being counted both as "1" and "0." This code works for a different subset of data that doesn't contain missing values. Why is it different for this dataset?

```
t1 <- data.frame(characteristic = rep(NA, 5), year = sample(x = 1990:1995, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

t1 %>% 
  select(YEAR, CHARACTERISTIC) %>%
  group_by(YEAR) %>% 
  mutate(YES = length(CHARACTERISTIC[CHARACTERISTIC == "1"]),
         NO = length(CHARACTERISTIC[CHARACTERISTIC == "0"]),
         COUNT = n(), 
         MISSING = sum(is.na(CHARACTERISTIC))) %>% 
  summarize(CHARACTERISTIC = paste(round(first(YES / COUNT) * 100, 2), "%"),
            NO_CHARACTERISTIC= paste(round(first(NO / COUNT) * 100, 2), "%"),
            MISSING = paste(round(first(MISSING / COUNT) * 100, 2), "%"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`length` when compared (`==`) with `NA` returns `NA` and when you subset a vector with `NA` it returns `NA`, hence `NA` is calculated in `length`.

Check this example :

```
x <- c(1:3, NA, 2:3, NA)
length(x)
#[1] 7

x == 3
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE    NA FALSE  TRUE    NA
x[x == 3]
#[1]  3 NA  3 NA
length(x[x == 3])
#[1] 4
```

Here, you expected output to be 2 but it gives 4 because of `NA` values. Perhaps, you can use :

```
length(na.omit(x[x == 3])) 
#[1] 2
```

but that is very convoluted use `sum` on logical values instead.

```
sum(x == 3, na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 2
```

So try :

```
library(dplyr)
t1 %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(YES = sum(characteristic == "1", na.rm = TRUE),
         NO = sum(characteristic == "0", na.rm = TRUE))
```